# Gorm: Cannot add or update a child row - a foreign key constraint fails on self referencing

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

I have a struct which looks like this:

```
type Category struct {
    Code           *int      `gorm:"unique;primaryKey;"`
    ParentCategory *Category `gorm:"foreignKey:Code"`
}
```

A **Category** itself can have a **ParentCategory** which is also from type **Category**. So it references to itself.
If its the first Category it has NO ParentCategory.

I have an array whith 4 Categories, as said, the first one doesnt have ab ParentCategory.

When saving these Categories one after one (Beginning with the first which has NO ParentCategory, I get these errors (Just print here the first two):

```
Error 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ps_product_service`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_categories_parent_category` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES `categories` (`code`))
[20.890ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `categories` (`code`) VALUES (0) RETURNING `code`
Error when creating category: Error 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ps_product_service`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_categories_parent_category` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES `categories` (`code`))&{Code:0x140003c6a00 ParentCategory:<nil>}
2023/06/19 21:31:44 Error 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ps_product_service`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_categories_parent_category` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES `categories` (`code`))
[7.689ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `categories` (`code`) VALUES (99) RETURNING `code`
Error when creating category: Error 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ps_product_service`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_categories_parent_category` FOREIGN KEY (`code`) REFERENCES `categories` (`code`))&{Code:0x140003c6a20 ParentCategory:<nil>}
```

I really cant figure out what I have to do here. Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have managed your requirements with the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/samber/lo"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type category struct {
    Code             uint `gorm:"unique;primaryKey;"`
    ParentCategoryId *uint
    ParentCategory   *category `gorm:"foreignKey:ParentCategoryId"`
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&category{})

    // load dummy data
    db.Create(&category{
        Code:             1,
        ParentCategoryId: nil,
    })
    db.Create(&category{
        Code:             2,
        ParentCategoryId: lo.ToPtr[uint](1),
    })
    db.Create(&category{
        Code:             3,
        ParentCategoryId: lo.ToPtr[uint](2),
    })
    db.Create(&category{
        Code:             4,
        ParentCategoryId: lo.ToPtr[uint](1),
    })

    // reading logic
    var categories []category
    if err := db.Model(&category{}).Find(&categories).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range categories {
        if v.ParentCategoryId == nil {
            fmt.Printf("id: %v\tparentCategoryId: <nil>\n", v.Code)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("id: %v\tparentCategoryId: %v\n", v.Code, *v.ParentCategoryId)
    }
}
```

If I got well your needs, you need to have a table that references itself. That's why I defined the `category` struct in this way. Each category has its own `ParentCategoryId` unless the category has no parent. If you try to execute the previous code, you should get something like:

```
id: 1   parentCategoryId: <nil>
id: 2   parentCategoryId: 1
id: 3   parentCategoryId: 2
id: 4   parentCategoryId: 1
```

Maybe I didn't get something from your question, if that's the case just let me know and I'll update my answer, thanks!